# "You're not the person WHO I thought you were" or "You're not the person WHOM I thought you were"?

Tags: whom, who

As the title says.

WHO is a subject relative pronoun, and WHOM is an object relative pronoun.

I tried finding an answer to this on the site, but this sentence in particular is more challenging than something like "She's the woman whom I married." (I married ***her***..."her" is the object of the sentence, so it's easy enough to say "Ah! This needs an object relative pronoun.")

I'm trying to reconfigure the sentence above in my mind to find the answer, but I'm having some issues. I feel the answer is "whom," but I'm not 100% on it at all.

"You're not the person who/whom I thought (that) you were" could be said as:

**I** thought (that) **you** were someone else.

**I** thought (that) **you** were a different type of person.

In these cases, even though the **you** is a subject pronoun (same as "he," "she," etc.), would it still count as being in the object position because "I thought **about you** (object pronoun) and thought **you** (subject pronoun) were a different person"?

There is the folksy (or perhaps a grammatically consistent and correct?) idea that if you can ask a question about a sentence and have the answer be an object pronoun (him, her, us, them, you as object), then you should use "whom." This also applies if you can recast the sentence to discover whether the noun in question can be replaced with a subject or object pronoun (as in the "She's the woman whom I married" = "I married ***her***" example above).

But it doesn't seem to apply in this case. Or at least, I can't think of the question to reach the answer, or of a way which recontextualizes the original sentence so it's clear whether I should use "who" or "whom."

There is also the idea that if you can place a noun or pronoun after a verb, that noun or pronoun is an object and you should therefore use "whom" to refer back to it. ("She kicked him" = "He was the one whom she kicked.")

...unless the answer is actually "WHO"?

Thoughts? And yes, I realize that "who" is standard and accepted in the vast majority of English conversations, and that no one would bat an eyelash if someone used "who" in this case (or almost every case!), but I'm still curious about this one at a "technically correct" formal level, and not at a common usage level.

My apologies for the scattered thoughts.

Comment: 1. This will probably be considered a duplicate of 100s. 2. You could use *that* instead, esp. in this case. 2. Subject vs. object is determined within isolation of the clause it's in, not the sentence as a whole. 4. Not 100% sure I've understood everything you meant.

Comment: @HippoSawrUs What would the two clauses be in this case? "You're not the person" and "Whom/Who I thought you were"? Or would "who/whom" be part of "You're not the person whom/who"? I've edited my original post for added clarity. Apologies for the word salad.

Comment: You can reduce the sentence to "You're not the person I thought you were" and eliminate the issue. (-:

Comment: @JimMack I'm fully aware of that fact! :-D Just doing some (perhaps needless) grammar chopping for an online post that I'm writing on the subject of who/whom.

Comment: Hint: would you say, "He was not the person I thought *him* was?"

Comment: It should. But, as I've said many times before and won't waste another answer on: **Don't Use _Whom_. Ever.** Even if you use it right, somebody will judge and may correct you. Just avoid the occasion of sin. Also, not that it matters, but _who_ is correct here and _whom_ isn't.

Comment: I don't believe in closing questions as duplicates of *closed* questions. So, where does someone post a new, better, answer?  **THIS question shows effort, research** and has a good insight. **The older question consists of two lines and was rightly closed for lack of research**.

Comment: Thanks, everybody. I have learned two things from all of this:

-the decision of whether to use "who" or "whom" is based on the clause it's associated with.

-if the clause has a pronoun or noun + a form of "to be," "who" or "whom" must agree with that pronoun.

In this case, since "who/whom" relates to "you were," the correct word is "who."

Good enough for me! And I agree with @JohnLawler regarding avoiding the use of "whom" in speaking, but it is still used by some in academic and other formal contexts, particularly in writing. Worth the headaches? No. But people are curious. :)

Comment: New question: What about these two sentences: That's who/whom I meant. / He's the one who/whom we picked. Would this follow the "be" verb recommendation of using "who," or am I mixing things up? ("That is he" and "He is the one. He!"?) Ha! My apologies.

Comment: The determining clause would be 'you were [who]' with the *who* (elided) standing in for the "the person" (also elided, in a sense): 'You're not the person I thought you were.' I wrote an answer to demonstrate that for you; I hope it's clear. It is hard to imagine invisible, intangible things; good question.

Answer (score 2):

> There is also the idea that if you can place a noun or pronoun after a verb, that noun or pronoun is an object and you should therefore use "whom" to refer back to it.

This is false, and your sentence provides an excellent example. The actual object of "thought" is the whole clause "(that) you were." *Within* that clause, the person under discussion (the "that") is a predicative complement, not an object, of "were." So, when you make it into a question, you would use "who," not "whom."

Comment: The rule usually stated is that if an accusative form is used  *me/her/him/us/them*, you can used *whom.* As a rule, pronouns functioning as PCs take accusative case in modern English for most speakers, and thus *whom* should be fine.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. That's true of most speakers, but not in the rare formal contexts in which *whom* is still used.

Comment: While this explains the appearance of a subject-pronoun in the rearranged sentence (where the **clause** is indeed the object), it doesn't explain the OP's real issue with "You're not the person whom I thought you were," or maybe "...the person whom I thought of".

Comment: @AndrewLeach Perhaps the following is possible... 

If we take "the person I thought you were," we could replace it with "him/her/them." More specifically: "You're not [him]," as in "You're not [the person whom I thought you were]." In this case, it's clearly "whom" (to my eyes), but I'm not sure if this is how the sentence/clause should be chopped up, or if there is more than one right answer and that either "who" or "whom" could work depending on how you frame each part of the sentence.

...or if it is indeed "who" as suggested above.

Comment: Or even more confusingly "You are not he whom I thought of" — although that sentence does accurately convey subject complement and object pronoun.

Comment: In pedantic formal English--the kind where you use "whom"--you would say "you were *he,*" not "you were *him,*" hence the use of "who" rather than "whom."

Comment: "That's true of most speakers, but not in the rare formal contexts in which whom is still used." <--- This is simply made up. Many, many, many speakers use *whom* in all sorts of contexts. Even those who profess not to use *whom* on this site can quickly be shown to be exaggerating about the death of *whom*, because a quick search will show several posts in which they've used it themselves. The same is *not* true of people who use nominative predicative complements. The two groups are not homogenous.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I have to say that first comment to you rather got up my nose as it is precisely in more formal contexts or ones with higher-register speakers that *whom* is used.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. OP is pretty clearly asking about using whom "correctly" in the formal-register way, given their concern about the details of correct pronoun substitution. It's possible that OP is asking exclusively about informal registers but I think it would be most reasonable to assume that they are asking about the formal use.

Comment: @alphabet The bit that I maintain you have made up is that the *whom*ers and the nominative PCers are the same speakers. I'm not saying anything particular about *whom*ers apart from that they are everywhere and nowhere near dying out even if they use it less frequently. Same is not true for nominative PC fetishists.

Answer (score 0):

*Who* is correct. Following the pattern you supplied . . .

> It’s:
> *She’s the woman **whom** [I married **her**].*
>
> Not:
> **She’s the woman **who** [I married **she**].*
>
> It’s:
> *You’re not the person **who** I thought that [you were **he**].*
>
> Not:
> **You’re not the person **whom** I thought that [you were **him**].*

I know what you’re going to say: “But *you were he* sounds wrong!” And you would be right about that. But there’s this “rule”: The pronouns on both sides of a linking verb (*were*, in this case) must be subject pronouns.

If you have more time on your hands, [explore *It is I* vs. *It is me*](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/articles/it-is-i-versus-it-is-me/).

You can see how uncommon *whom [pronoun] thought [pronoun] [verb(be)]* is by comparing these from the Corpus of Contemporary American English:

[`who PRON thought PRON _vb`](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=113148540) and [`whom PRON thought PRON _vb`](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=113148554)

However the preponderance of *who*s is likely not due to supreme grammar knowledge but rather to the decline in the use of *whom* in all but formal or academic contexts.

Comment: I've seen it suggested that you use objective pronouns for subject complements, e.g. in the Cambridge Dictionary [link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/subject-complements)

Answer (score 0):

H&P's *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Pages 466-67) says that (in a certain dialect) *whom* is possible as the subject of a content clause embedded in a relative clause:

> **(e) Subject of an embedded content clause** 
> ...
> Attested examples of relative *whom* are given in [39], where [i] represents the usual type with a tensed verb (*thought*), while [ii] has a plain-form verb in the mandative construction: 
> [39] i *A man with a large waxed moustache and a mop of curly damp hair, **whom** Hal thought might be his uncle Fred, said, ‘That’s a fine bird you’re carving, Bert.’* 
> ii *It turns out that the woman, **whom** the police have asked not be identified, was a talented pianist and an unpublished writer.* 
> Prescriptive grammarians commonly treat this *whom* as a hypercorrection: since the pronoun is in subject function, the argument goes, it should be nominative and the accusative is therefore incorrect, attributable to a concern to avoid the common ‘error’ of using nominative *who* in place of accusative *whom*. This is another place, however, where we believe it is invalid to talk in terms of hypercorrection. The accusative variant has a long history and is used by a wide range of speakers; examples are quite often encountered in quality newspapers and works by respected authors. It has to be accepted as an established variant of the standard language. Thus there are in effect two dialects with respect to the case of embedded subjects, though they are not distinguished on any regional basis. Dialect A, which selects nominative, has more speakers and is the one recommended by the manuals, but there is no reason to say that it is inherently better or more grammatically correct than Dialect B, which selects accusative: the dialects just have different rules.

Now, this is a little different from your example *You're not the person whom I thought you were*, where *whom* is not the subject but the predicative complement of a content clause embedded in a relative clause.

CGEL continues to hypothesize the reasoning behind these different dialects:

> The alternation between *who* and *whom* can be attributed to the tension between the function of *who* with respect to the embedded content clause and its position in the relative clause. The two relevant factors are: 
> [40] i ***Who*** is subject of a finite content clause. 
> ii ***Who*** is in prenuclear position preceding the subject of the relative clause. 
> In Dialect A it is factor [i] that determines the case, as nominative, while in Dialect B [ii] is the determining factor, at least in formal style (and excluding the rather rare construction where ***who*** is in predicative complement function). In Dialect B the crucial distinction is therefore between relative clause subject and non-subject.

Dialect B is the dialect that allows the accusative in CGEL, so factor [ii] is the one we should be looking at to determine whether the same accusative is possible as the predicative complement of a content clause embedded in a relative clause. Because your example *You're not the person whom I thought you were* does satisfy factor [ii], I see no reason why *whom* cannot be allowed in Dialect B.

Having said all that, OP's particular construction with *whom* is extremely rare, although I was able to find one:

> *The more Brooke denies it, the more he will feel that she is not the person **whom** he thought she was.*

([TV Season & Spoilers](https://www.tvseasonspoilers.com/news/the-bold-and-the-beautiful-spoilers-for-october-3-2022/))

Somehow, the construction without the antecedent sounds more natural:

> *The woman he shot wasn’t **whom** he thought she was.*
> ([KGET](https://www.kget.com/news/crime-watch/bakersfield-gang-member-killed-woman-in-case-of-mistaken-identity-report-says/))

Comment: H&P clearly only intend for this to apply to the case where who/whom is the subject in an embedded clause, not to the case in which it is a predicative complement. They discuss the role of who/whom as a predicative complement earlier in the chapter and do not make an exception applying to subordinate clauses, as they do with subjects.

Comment: @alphabet If it's possible in a Subject it's clearly possible in a PC. If you look at the CaGEL description of when Dialect B speakers use whom, this is clearly one such case.

Comment: + 1  There is at least a strong case that the general rule is actually the one attributed to dialect B speakers. People who use *whom* do so in variation with *who* (i.e. they'll often, if not usually, use *who* instead of *whom*). The rule for omitting the relative word altogether is the Dialect B rule and it shouldn't surprise us if the two were the same. Furthermore, Dialect A *whom* situations are a subset of Dialect B ones. There's no evidence Dialect A exists!

Comment: @alphabet "They discuss the role of who/whom as a predicative complement earlier in the chapter" --> Could you be kind enough to give me the page numbers? I can't seem to figure out what section you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

First, this is a saying, which varies somewhat.

> You're not the person that I thought you were.
>
> You're not the person I thought you were.
>
> You're not who I thought you were.

Also, "the person" in question is an idealized personality *that* doesn't exist anymore, technically. That could be splitting hairs, but relative clause lessons found online (BBC and British Council) do not even include *whom* as an option. They have plucked that word right out ('Finito!') of existence in that context.

That being said, onto the problem at hand: *who* vs. *whom* for illustrative purposes.

Sometimes it helps to see the clauses separated. Take the easier example first.

> She's the woman (who/whom) I married.
>
> She's *the woman* + I married [*the woman*] =
> She's the woman (who/whom) I married [DO → objective case] =
> She's the woman whom I married.
>
> 'She's the woman I married.'

Now for the example in question, which is harder to visualize (as intangibles would be):

> You're not the person (who/whom) I thought you were.
>
> You're not "the person" + I thought you were ["the person"] =
> You're not the person (who/whom) I thought you were [PN → subjective/nominative] =
> You're not the person who I thought you were.
>
> 'You're not the person I thought you were.'

This is just reconfiguring the sentences, as requested, in a fundamental way (see link below).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause#Bound_and_free

[British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/relative-clauses-defining-relative-clauses) (basic information on current usage, omitting pronouns, etc.)

Comment: "You're not who I thought you were" is not a relative clause but a fused relative construction, and a weird one too (because it doesn't require the *ever* suffix on *who*). *Whom* does not occur in fused relative constructions. (And so the BC aren't going to start recommending it in them). Secondly, the relative pronoun *who* in your last triple of examples, does not refer to the Subject *you*, but the missing predicative complement *you*, which if it had any visible case would be accusative, not nominative.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. - 1. You're referring to the wrong sentence. 2. The BC doesn't even mention *whom,* period. 3. No one said *who* refers to *you* except you (*you* = "the person" means "the person" renames *you,* always).

Comment: You indicate that the *you* under consideration is the one in the RC. There's no other sensible way of interpreting your example. Especially given the subjective/nominative case comment in brackets.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. - I've edited, to make the 2nd step clearer, and added a relevant source. Again, *who* does not refer to *you* (*who* stands in for "the person" which happens to rename *you*). I headed each triplet with the sample sentence being dissected, for added clarity.

Answer (score -3):

You could make your alternative examples more clear by using a pronoun that does have different subject and object forms.

Would you ever say this?

> (*) He was not the person I thought him was.

Of course not. You're not even tempted to consider this "technically correct".

For the same reason, *who* and not *whom* is the correct pronoun in your example.

Comment: Well, of course, because *was* (in both cases) takes a subject complement. But the sentence in the title is what is being asked about.

Answer (score -4):

Please realize that the question of who vs whom has been asked in this stack before. This question is a duplicate of other existing questions.

A lot of modern Emglish gurnaths would profess (but not confess) that the word "whom" has largely been euthanized and archaicized, replaced by the word "who".

But old folks like me and being indoctrinated by an archaic British type of education, are not quite done with the word "whom" yet. I persist in using the word "whom" as it provides more precision about whom I am referencing.

It's quite simple: to see if you could substitute "who" with "me", "him", "her" or "them", then you would know if "whom" is appropriately placed.

- To whom we give thanks, praise to Almighty Allah.

  - To him we give thanks, praise to Almighty Allah.
- To whom we give thanks, as we venerate Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva.

  - To them we give thanks, as we venerate Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva.
- To whom we give thanks, as our supplications to Jesus-god, father-god and spirit-god.

  - To them we give thanks, as supplications to Jesus-god, father-god and spirit-god.

I think modern folks should not abandon the understanding and familiarity with the concept of "dative" or "accusative".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dative_case.

Roughly,

- whom = recipient of action
- who = perpetrator of action

Them, him, her, me - are dative targets.

- Tell her to come home, as she needs to rest

  - To whom I want to come home, is one who also needs to rest.
- I want her home that she need rest

  - Whom I want home, who also needs rest.
- With them the Force will be, they are the salvation

  - With whom the Force will be, are those who are the salvation
- That to him I am married, is not your concern.

  - That to whom I am married, is not your concern.

Let me refer you to the famous buffalo expression.

- Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo bufallo Buffalo buffalo

Where the word buffalo also means "bully", and where the plural of words like buffalo, fish, deer are spelled the same as the singular, the expression about the city of Buffalo may be explained by

- Buffalo cattle Buffalo deer bully, bully Buffalo fish.
- Buffalo cattle whom Buffalo deer bully, they bully Buffalo fish.

Therefore,

- Buffalo buffalo whom Buffalo buffalo buffalo, who in turn buffalo other Buffalo buffalo.

Without the use of the dative "whom", the explanation would not be quite as succint.

- Buffalo buffalo who Buffalo buffalo buffalo, who in turn buffalo other Buffalo buffalo.

Comment: It is unethical to downvote this answer for the reason of being religiously offended.

Comment: No downvote from me, but the 2 downvotes were possibly cast because you explained how to use "whom" but you didn't answer the question. Should it be **whom** or **who** in the OP's statement? It seems you are advocating for *whom*, could you make that a little clearer in your answer, please?

Comment: Downvote from me because your examples are ungrammatical.

Comment: My attitude is to enlighten with rhe principle which should be used to draw the answer.

Comment: Have this forun been invaded by novices who should be at English Learners ' stack?

Comment: Erm... “HAS this forum been invaded…” and just to mention one another  `That to whom I am married, is not your concern.` is better expressed as "TO whom I am married [is none of your concern.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is+none+of+your+concern%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AJOqlzVhK7Klpl6XGJv12c1Ry0MnzNtfaQ:1679258869436&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1999&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiN25fj7uj9AhXHhv0HHavGDEYQpwV6BAgBECM&biw=1151&bih=629&dpr=2.5)”

Comment: "is not your concern" is legitimate and acceptable. e.g,, My concern is for your health. My concern, your concern, his concern, Not your concern.

Comment: My examples have some yodaistic structures, unusual but acceptable.

Comment: @BlessedGeek Perhaps I should have asked this at English Learners' Stack, but it seems that even non-novices in this community are having a hard time coming up with an answer that everyone can agree upon. Difficult this is.